# Do we log duplicate data in tables or keep joining on all future reads?

Tags: database, database-design

Say a user activity table. At a minimum you would need stuff like user_id, datetime, activity_id, object_id, etc. I can join up with object table to find the object owner. I can join with activity table to find the activity group, type, etc.

OR

I can copy those details at runtime into the activity table also. This only means duplicate data but in the future whenever i need to read i do not have to keep joining. I have all my data now in the activity table for all possible pieces of data.

If i do duplicate data, do i duplicate it with FK or standalone?

Comment: Thanks. I added a link, if you are interested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Certainly Databases should be Normalised, because they perform better, SQL was designed for Normalised structures, and for joining them. There is no reason to "de-normalise".

However, there is one case which has an exceptional need.  History tables or Log fies.  The question to be considered is, when you query this table, do you need the current data from the parent object; or is this a true log of what happened at the time, and you need the data that was current at the time the log row was created.

In the latter case, since there is an explicit purpose in storing such data, it is not actually a duplicate, it is not a reversal of the Normalisation; therefore, it is incorrect to *classify* the data as duplicate or "denormalised".  It is just Audit data, which must be retained.  Generally Log files (that's what they really are; we store them in the database for convenience) are not part of the database, and database rules do not apply.

But always implement indices on them, and purge them regularly; otherwise the turn into monsters.

The alternative to Log files is History tables.  Rather than a Log file for actions, this is implemented on a table basis, as needed. For each table for which an Audit of changes must be retained,  a "copy" of the table is implemented. This stores the before-image of rows that have been changed. The DDL is exactly the same as the source table, plus one item: the PK has a TIMESTAMP or DATETIME column added.  There too, it is by explicit requirement, and it would be incorrect to *classify* these tables as duplicate or "de-normalised".

History tables are superior to Log files, because they store **only** the rows that have been changed; whereas Log files store unchanging data repeatedly.  The resulting volumes of data stored are quite different.

[**▶Example of History Tables◀**](http://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Student%20Resolutions/Mark%20DM.pdf)

Comment: In practice, a very common approach to building an audit/history table involves TWO OR THREE extra columns: (1) the above-mentioned "timestamp". (2) "user_who_caused_change" column. (3) For tables which must be fed to other systems (e.g. data warehouse) via an interface, "INS/DEL/UPD_OLD/UPD_NEW" flag (the latter flag is fairly often a subset, e.g. you don't need to store UPD_OLD values in the audit table and you can merge "UPD_NEW" and "INS" into a "NEW". This 3rd column makes it easier to do warehouse feed without cumbersome queries against main table.

Comment: @DVK. Oh, I am sure there are various practices out there. 2) In reasonable quality databases, the UpdatedUser is already in the Data table; therefore it is carried to the History table as data, no additional column required. To be clear, the Data table contains the Last UpdatedUser and UpdatedDtm; the History table has the before-images of all previous rows, plus the AuditDtm. Refer to the link in my answer.

Comment: 3) So if (a) this is not a data warehouse question and (b) the flag is not in the History table, why exactly are we discussing it ? Separately, the data warehouses I use are driven off UpdatedDtm, there is no need for flags in the source Db.

Comment: @PerformanceDBA - why exactly would you put a useless (except for auditing purposes) "updated by this user" field into a primary table in a "reasonable quality" database instead of in an audit table diectly?

Comment: @PerformanceDBA - Because without "ins/upd/del" flag the feeds to DataWarehouse need to query main table (e.g. to find out if a record was deleted by adding "not exist in main table" joins). Someone as brilliant as you should surely see that querying main table for a data warehouse feed may NOT always be the most desirable option.

Comment: @DVK. Er, because the Auditors require it, to identify the "useless" user who changed the **current** row; the History table may or may not exist, so it has to be in the main table.  Standard practice in my ambit.  Well there a lots of large warehouses that perform operations that you are evidently unaware of; and **do not** perform operations that you evidently think is "common practice".  And detail them in non-warehouse questions.

Comment: @PerformanceDBA - (1) Auditors don't care whether the user comes from main or audit table. They just care that you have a process for identifying the user. (2) Since we are discussing Audit tables, the "audit table may not exist" is not really relevant example of why a main table **which has an Audit table** needs a user field.

Comment: @PerformanceDBA - (3) If you look carefully, I didn't say a SINGLE word about what data warehouses do or do not. I was specifically talking about an OUTSIDE-of-DW data feed used to transmit info from non-DW database to a (frequently, a different company's) DW.

Comment: @DVK. (1) Sure. You know about Auditors. Sure.  And banking systems. Why don't you post a new question I can answer all your issues. Comments are restrictive. (3) I can still see your reference to DWs in comment #1.I t is the cumbersome that is a worry.  Give it to an experienced SQL coder.

Answer (score 3):

What you are talking about is called [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) (or in your case [de-normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Denormalization)).

Since a relational database is pretty much designed to perform joins, there is usually VERY little reason to de-normalize and store duplicate data in one big wide table (there are some edge cases and tradeoffs, but in the example you used they don't really apply, so I recommend sticking with 3-table approach you listed (activity, user_activity, object).

Comment: Normalization conflicts with reports. Report performance is determined by full scan performance, so you plan proper partitioning, pre-aggregations, etc, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema